# How to get distance to places from DB given longitude and latitude

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

I want to select the places from the DB in 10 km range around the place where I am.
For example, when select `Location_1` in my sample DB, I want to get Locations like the above condition from DB.
I use Yii2 now.

This is my DB table sample named 'places'

```
ID          Location        Longitude   Latitude
----------- ---------- ---------- -----------
1           Location_1      30.8505081  14.2575487
2           Location_2      30.828072   14.1554811
3           Location_3      30.850763   14.250705
4           Location_4      30.8484719  14.252653
```

Now, I have no idea how to get from the Longitude and Latitude to the distance from my current location.

Comment: Rephrased question, removed appeals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. The location's latitude is 14.2575487 and longitude is 30.8505081 from where you are finding the results from the table within 10 Kms.

```
SELECT *,ROUND(  1.609 * 3956 * 2  * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((14.2575487 - ABS(Latitude)) * PI()/180 / 2),2) + COS(14.2575487 * PI()/180 ) * COS(ABS(Latitude) * PI()/180) * POWER(SIN((30.8505081 - Longitude ) * PI()/180 / 2), 2) )),0) AS distance FROM places WHERE 1=1  HAVING distance<= 10
```